# Send http request over https connection ASP IIS

Tags: http, iis, asp-classic, https, iis-7.5

I have a legacy Asp web site. It's working fine when accessing via http protocol. When we access it via https protocol (https://xyz.com/mainpage.asp), page is not working well. I found web page is using framesets and in that it is accessing other web pages using http protocol (http://xyz.com/subpage1.asp). Internet Explorer error displaying as "Access denied" for http Uri (http://xyz.com/subpage1.asp). I am not in the position to change all webpage requests to http. Is there any way to solve this using any IIS configuration?

Server - IIS 7.5
Browser - IE 9.

Thanks,

Sumesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using URL Rewrite module.

Please install URL rewrite module then do following steps.
A nice tutorial for this is at http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/